# gym 0.21 + stable_baseline3 TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm trying to train a `stable_baseline3` model on my custom `gym` environment. The training crashes with a `TypeError` on the first step.

```
Using cuda device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_agent.py", line 12, in <module>
    model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py", line 307, in learn
    return super().learn(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py", line 236, in learn
    total_timesteps, callback = self._setup_learn(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py", line 408, in _setup_learn
    self._last_obs = self.env.reset()  # pytype: disable=annotation-type-mismatch
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py", line 75, in reset
    self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/foo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py", line 107, in _save_obs
    self.buf_obs[key][env_idx] = obs[key]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The custom gym is based on the [official tutorial](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/environment_creation/) plus some minor modifications like replacing `self._np_random` with `np.random.randint` because that method does not appear to exist in `gym==0.21.0`.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

**train_agent.py**

```py
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: gym.make("gym_envs:gym_envs/GridWorld-v0")])

model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)  # TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**gym_envs/envs/grid_world.py**

```py
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np


class GridWorldEnv(gym.Env):
    metadata = {"render_modes": [], "render_fps": 4}

    def __init__(self, render_mode=None, size=5):
        self.size = size
        self.window_size = 512

        self.observation_space = spaces.Dict(
            {
                "agent": spaces.Box(0, size - 1, shape=(2,), dtype=int),
                "target": spaces.Box(0, size - 1, shape=(2,), dtype=int),
            }
        )

        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(4)

        self._action_to_direction = {
            0: np.array([1, 0]),
            1: np.array([0, 1]),
            2: np.array([-1, 0]),
            3: np.array([0, -1]),
        }

        assert render_mode is None or render_mode in self.metadata["render_modes"]
        self.render_mode = render_mode

        self.window = None
        self.clock = None

    def _get_obs(self):
        return {"agent": self._agent_location, "target": self._target_location}

    def _get_info(self):
        return {
            "distance": np.linalg.norm(
                self._agent_location - self._target_location, ord=1
            )
        }

    def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
        self._agent_location = np.random.randint(0, self.size, (2, 2))
        self._target_location = self._agent_location
        while np.array_equal(self._target_location, self._agent_location):
            self._target_location = np.random.randint(0, self.size, (2, 2))

        observation = self._get_obs()
        info = self._get_info()
        if self.render_mode == "human":
            self._render_frame()
        return observation, info

    def step(self, action):
        direction = self._action_to_direction(action)
        self._agent_location = np.clip(
            self._agent_location + direction, 0, self.size - 1
        )
        terminated = np.array_equal(self._agent_location, self._target_location)
        reward = 1 if terminated else 0
        observation = self._get_obs()
        info = self._get_info()

        if self.render_mode == "human":
  - `             self._render_frame()

        return observation, reward, terminated, False, info

    def render(self):
        pass

    def close(self):
        pass
```

pip packages:

- gym                        0.21.0
- gym-notices                0.0.8
- stable-baselines3          1.7.0

---

If the `env` is not vectorized, then we get the same error, probably because `stable_baselines3` will still wrap it with a `DummyVecEnv`.

```py
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import ppo

env = gym.make("gym_envs:gym_envs/GridWorld-v0")

model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env, tensorboard_log="./logs/", verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

From gym v0.26.0, `Env.reset` returns 2 components and `Env.step` does 5, which has broken backward compatibility.(https://github.com/openai/gym/releases)

Since you are using v.0.21, they should be like following.

```
def reset(self, seed=None, options=None):
    # ...
    return observation

def step(self, action):
    # ...
    return observation, reward, terminated, info
```